# Can't get 1st item to reset in a html select using angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, drop-down-menu

My drop down works fine when I initially open it up inside a modal window.
If I change the select to some selection drop value then close the modal and reopen, it stays the same. It doesn't reset it to 'None selected'

Here is what I'm doing

```js
// in my ts file when I open the modal
this.geModal.state = '';
```

```html
<select class="form-control" name="prState">
                <option [selected]="geModal.state == ''">None selected</option>
                <option *ngFor="let state of stateList"
                [value]="state.code" [selected]="geModal.state == state.code">
                    {{state.name}}
                </option>
            </select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not mix `[selected]` with `[ngModel]`, don't use a default value for `state` and set `value="undefined"` for the default option:

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="geModal.state" name="prState">
  <option value="undefined">None selected</option>
  <option *ngFor="let state of stateList" [value]="state.code">{{state.name}}</option>
</select>
```